# How do I apply CSS3 transition to all properties except background-position?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'd like to apply a CSS transition to all properties apart from background-position.
I tried to do it this way:

```
.csstransitions a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;                  
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;                 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;   
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;          
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.csstransitions a {
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0s ease 0s;                 
    -moz-transition: background-position 0s ease 0s;                
    -o-transition: background-position 0s ease 0s;  
    -ms-transition: background-position 0s ease 0s;         
    transition: background-position 0s ease 0s;
}
```

First I set all properties to transition and then I tried to overwrite solely the transition for the background-position property.

However this seems to also reset all other properties - so basically none of the transitions seem to happen any more.

Is there a way to do this without listing all properties?

Comment: Hi, i am actually looking for this issue. Did you get any acceptable answer ?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Here's a solution that also works on Firefox:

```
transition: all 0.3s ease, background-position 1ms;
```

I made a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aWzwh/

Comment: For some reason `1ms` didn't work for me, but `0` did.

Comment: @Flimm, what browser are you using? And what do you mean with "didn't work", didn't animate anything?

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't take `0` as a accepted parameter for transitions but 1ms seems to do the trick

Comment: For me `1ms` didn't worked, but  `1ms none` did! @ericsoco `0ms` or `0s` works, too.

Comment: Units of time MUST have a unit. So 0 doesn't work just like 4 won't work, but 4s will work just as 0s will work.

Comment: Be aware of there're differences among even modern browsers. check out my answer below.

Comment: I applied this property, and while my background image doesn't 'dance' anymore in Safari, it still animates in every major browser I've tested. Thus, I don't see how this answers the original question.

Answer (score 21):

Hope not to be late. It is accomplished using only one line!

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0, height 0, top 0, left 0;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0, height 0, top 0, left 0;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0, height 0, top 0, left 0;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0, height 0, top 0, left 0;
```

That works on Chrome. You have to separate the CSS properties with a comma.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/H2jet/

Comment: I'm trying this on Chrome, and it doesn't seem to work for me. The `all` transition-property seems to override all the others no matter what.

Comment: @animuson see my edited post, I added a jsfiddle example. In fact, it is not working in Mozilla yet, but it is in Chrome

Comment: Interesting. I guess I hadn't tested it with other properties. When I tried `color 0` it worked, but it is certainly not working with `background-position 0`. Even `background 0` produces no results for me... [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7zHW/) I rigged up from the Gaming.SE menu. To be honest I only even tested `background-position` initially because that's what the question specifically mentions and is the one I was trying to change myself.

Comment: It used to work on chrome for me. It's still working in IE11 but as of this week the all property now overrides anything later on the line.

Comment: As @cirrus said, Chrome doesn't honor a 0 second duration anymore, but you can make it work giving a very short duration instead, like `.1ms`

Comment: This works on both Chrome and Firefox if a non-zero second duration is supplied.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I copied it as is. But I got it working by adding `0s` instead of `0`. Mentioning the `s` after `0` made it work

Answer (score 10):

You can try using the standard W3C way:

```
.transition { transition: all 0.2s, top 0s, left 0s, width 0s, height 0s; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H2jet/60/

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
* {
    transition: all .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
}
a {
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-position 1ms linear;
    transition: background-position 1ms linear;
}
```

Comment: "try this" code-only answers aren't the best.  Better is some explanation of what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looks for a shorthand way, to add transition for all properties **except for one specific property with delay**, be aware of there're **differences** among even modern browsers.

A simple demo below shows the difference. Check out [full code](https://codepen.io/iplus26/pen/PaVXxG)

```
div:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 2s, border-radius 2s 4s;
}
```

Chrome will "combine" the two animation (which is like I expect), like below:

[image]

While Safari "separates" it (which may not be expected):

[image]

A more compatible way is that you assign the specific transition for specific property, if you have a delay for one of them.

Comment: Indeed.  This is critical insight.  As lame is it is to have to specify each property individually rather than `all`, it's useful to know that it's the only way to get the desired behavior across browsers.

Comment: Do you mean using the `all` keyword will cause issues? So is it recommended to specifically mention each transition? and is this still an issue after 3 years?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
-webkit-transition: all .2s linear, background-position 0;
```

This worked for me on something similar..

Comment: fixing background-position to 0 is not = to removing transition from background-position. Isn't it ?

Comment: This cannot ever work. By re-defining the transition property afterwards, you completely override the previous transition property, as if it never existed. They do not get consolidated.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I copied it as is. But I got it working by adding `0s` instead of `0`. Mentioning the `s` after `0` made it work