# How to animate all except one feature with CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I have a simple question.

I would like to give an "all" animation to a text area, however I do not want it to animate the text shadow on focus.

How can I make exceptions when I'm using the following:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    background: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just leave the `text-shadow` property untouched?

Comment: Because when people click on the textbox, all of the text will be highlighted by jQuery in the textbox and it looks kinda bad, that a text with shadow is highlighted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply CSS3 transition to all properties except background-position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604389/how-do-i-apply-css3-transition-to-all-properties-except-background-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple, just set the rule for all of them, then set it again for just the text-shadow:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    background: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
    transition:text-shadow 0s;
    -webkit-transition:text-shadow 0s;
    -moz-transition:text-shadow 0s;
}
```

With this code, if you change the text-shadow, it will instantly change, rather than animate. Like @Patrick commented, if you dont want the text-shadow to change at all, then make sure you don't edit that property.

Comment: No problem! please choose this as the correct answer, then. :D

Comment: FYI this doesn't "fix" it.. it just overrides the `all 0.5s` with `text-shadow 0s`, you no longer have the `all` transition..

Comment: Yes, it just overrides. Correct answer in here — http://stackoverflow.com/a/24371094/2570353.

Answer (score 10):

You can also write like this, if you don't want overwrite the transition property :

```
input[type=text]:focus {
background: #fff;
transition:all 0.5s, text-shadow 0s;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s, text-shadow 0s;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s, text-shadow 0s;
}
```